# Store offset in local file

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am using Confluent.Kafka 0.9.5 and follows its example [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AdvancedConsumer/Program.cs).

A difference from its example is: I wanna store the offset locally. So I initialized the configuration as below.

```
    private static Dictionary<string, object> ConstructConfig(string brokerList)
    {
        string dir = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "cache", "kafka");
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        return new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "group.id", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Cluster.Name") },
            { "offset.store.method", "file" },  // Offset commit store method: 'file' - local file store 
            { "offset.store.path", dir }, // Path to local file for storing offsets. 
            { "offset.store.sync.interval.ms", 0 }, // Use -1 to disable syncing; and 0 for immediate sync after each write. 
            { "enable.auto.commit", false },
            { "statistics.interval.ms", 60000 },
            { "bootstrap.servers", brokerList },
            { "default.topic.config", new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    { "auto.offset.reset", "smallest" }
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

I receives the message successfully, and called `CommitAsync` for each of them.

```
           while (true)
           {
               try
               {
                   msg = null;
                   if (!consumer.Consume(out msg, ts))
                       continue;
                   OnMessage(msg);

                   log.InfoFormat($"Offset = {msg.Offset}");

                   await consumer.CommitAsync(msg);
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   // ...
                   break;
               }
           }
```

But there is no file created in the target directory. When I start the app again, I receive the same messages. Surely I have write permission on the `offset.store.path`

Why there is no offset stored?

Comment: Late comment: I'm guessing `CommitAsync` is doing some background work, and you have not closed the consumer otherwise to notify it to flush the offsets